# How to calculate PWM duty cycles for Solenoid current control

Tags: pwm

How to calculate the PWM duty cycle for Solenoid current control

I am trying to design a current control driver for Solenoid. I know the peak and the holding current range for solenoid.
How would I find the PWM duty cycle based on the current that I need to control?

Solenoid resistance at different temperature

1.1 Ohm @ 20 C
1.61 Ohm @ 150 C
0.85 Ohm @ -40 C

Voltage Range
9 V min
13 V Normal
16 V Max

Current Range

Disengaging clutch current 7 A min & Max 16 A, but I would like to limit the max current up to 10 A only.

Holding current for clutch is 1.2 A min to 2.2 Max

Frequency Range: 1000 to 50 Hz

Microcontroller is used for PWM output.

I want to design a current control circuitry using N MOSFETS for Solenoid

I am using current sense opamp to monitor the current through solenoid.  I am using 20 m Ohm resistance for the current measurement.

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the PWM duty cycle for the disengaging current & holding current?

Should I go 100% duty cycle and control the current once the clutch is disengaged by the solenoid?

Answer (score 1):

If you separate out the solenoid coil into its two main parts

1) resistance
2) inductance

you can determine the duty required reasonably accurately

**What duty required to overcome the resistive component?**

determine the voltage drop (pull-in current * resistance)

determine the duty to overcome this (Vr/Vdc)*100

**What duty required to manage the current?**

utilising \$V = L\frac{\delta i}{\delta t}\$

and knowing the voltage you are applying to the coil (Vdc - Vr), the inductance and the ripple you want to tolerate. This will give you an ON-TIME.

With the duty known for the resistive component and now the duty for the inductive component, a reasonable estimate of the required duty for pullin & hold can be determined.